# Connecting PHP to SFTP using phpseclib

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I need to connect to a SFTP server to upload files using PHP (PHP version: 5.3.13).

I'm trying to use phpseclib but I get the following error:

> Notice: No compatible server to client encryption algorithms found in [...]\phpseclib1.0.2\Net\SSH2.php on line 1375
>   Login Failed

The code I'm using is:

```
    include(CfgPath .'/phpseclib1.0.2/Net/SFTP.php');
    include(CfgPath .'/phpseclib1.0.2/Crypt/Random.php');
    $port = 22;
    $sftp = new Net_SFTP($host, $port);
    if (!$sftp->login($user, $pass)) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    } else { echo 'Sucess'; }
```

Any idea of what might be causing this problem and how to solve it?
Thank you!

Comment: please include your source code, how you are connecting to SFTP server

Comment: Code added, thank you!

Comment: crypt that you included is not compatible with your SFTP server. you should choose another one

Comment: If i don't include Random.php I'll get this error: Call to undefined function phpseclib_resolve_include_path()

Comment: add this at the top `set_include_path(CfgPath .'/phpseclib1.0.2/');` and test please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this at the top set_include_path(CfgPath .'/phpseclib1.0.2/'); like Denis Alimov suggested solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I added this line above all the line

`set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib1.0.2');`

The PHP file is looking for a plugin which can be found at `\xampp\php\PEAR` for client encryption.